# If G has p isolated points and no K2 components, then ω(G) ≤ q + p

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading "intersection graphs" from frank hararys graph theory book, page 19

As the title states, it says if G has p isolated points and no k2 components then intersection number of G would be less than q ( i believe number of edges ) + p ( number of isolated points )

How do i prove this? I first tried to formulate an example but i couldn't

- G is the graph
- s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 are the sub-sets of S used for creating intersection graph
- we get 2 edges through intersection

I don't understand, at the end the entire S would be required in order for the intersection graph to be isomorphic to G, so we would end up with 7 as the minimum number of elements, hence intersection number would be 7 but it isn't less than or equal to q + p

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the elements $v_2,v_3,v_4$ from the sets $S_2,S_3,S_4$, and it would still be the same intersection graph. More generally, for each vertex $v$ which is not isolated, define the set to be the set of edges incident on $v$. The number of elements used is the number of edges. Plus one new element for every isolated vertex.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it solved my problem :)

I am so embarrassed, as soon as i read your answer it hit me that "the number of points in an intersection graph are the number of subsets present and not the actual elements of the set, so eliminating the extra non - elements would not affect the graph"